# Programatically scroll not working for TableView inside collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview

I have a ViewController that has a CollectionView. Every cell of this collection has a TableView.

I want to be able to do scroll to IndexPath in the table view. To do this I use the next function:

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Doing debugging I see that this is executed with the correct indexpath but it doesn't works, the TableView doesn't do anything.

I'm doing the same in other parts of my application and it works, but I think the problem is the TableView is inside a Collection but I need this structure.

Screenshot of design:

[image]

Collection view starts below "Resultados" to the bottom of the screen. Inside I have a collection that starts below "Eosinofilos"

Thanks

Comment: Will be better if you can share a screenshot of your design.

Answer (score 0):

try this
it will scroll to the 0 row.

```
wbTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: It doesn't works, is the function I'm using, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: How u r scrolling table view at 0 indexes?

tap on any button or ..?

Comment: When tap an element of the chart, I match the point touched with the element in table view. I debbuged this and it works, it finds the index path in the table that matches with the point user touched.